# Change ActiveAdmin deletion method

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I'm creating a voucher system for a website and I don't want to give the right to the admins to delete the voucher and instead of the deletion link I only want to update my field status from enable to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cherry-pick the actions you want, then create a "disable" member action:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Voucher do
  actions :all, except: [:destroy]

  member_action :disable, :method => :put do
    voucher = Voucher.find(params[:id])
    voucher.update_attribute!(:status, "disabled")
  end

  action_item only: [:show] do
    unless voucher.status == "disabled"
      link_to("Disable", disable_admin_voucher_path(voucher), method: 'put')
    end
  end
end
```